# Angular - how to handle double binding and validation?

Tags: angular, typescript

This question started when trying to implement a complex component (a date and time input), with a clear "state" (the composite timestamp) held by the parent component.
The parent uses a child component (a numeric field) which employs double binding to update the relevant portion of the state.

The child doesn't know (nor should) the full validation logic, so it is going to emit (via an `Output` property) all of it's value changes.
Some of this values will result in invalid state (say a timestamp over the maximum allowed). In this case, I would like to stop the propagation of the event, and have the parent component "reset" the state of the child.

However, this doesn't happen, because (as far as change detection is concerned) the state of the parent has not changed, so the *`input`* property of the child is not reset.

I reduced this problem to the very minimum on [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-edts1r).

The core of the problem, however, is simply this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-child",
  template: `
    Value on the child: {{ value }}<br />
    <button (click)="value = value + 1">Increment</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  private _value = 0;
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  @Input() set value(v: number) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.valueChange.emit(v);
    }
  }

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div>The value on the parent is: {{ parentValue }}</div>
    <my-child [(value)]="parentValue"></my-child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  _parentValue = 0;
  get parentValue() {
    return this._parentValue;
  }
  set parentValue(v: number) {
    // discard values more than 5 because they are "invalid"
    // probably I shouldn't just "return", but what to do?
    if (this.isInvalid(v)) return;
    this._parentValue = v;
  }

  isInvalid(v: number) {
    return v > 5;
  }
}
```

Clicking on the child will take the child `value` over 5, while the `parentValue` will keep it's maximum of 5. And, because `parentValue` is not changing, the change detection will not set the input property in the child component.

What should be the best way to have the parent fully own the state and "reset" it's children when appropriate? I could use `ViewChildren` and hack my way through it, but the real case is obviously a lot more complex, and I'm searching for a general pattern to follow.

Comment: Is there a reason that having the child expose a `reset` method that the parent would access using `ViewChild` wouldn't work? You mention using `ViewChildren` and hacking your way through it, but that seems like a clean approach--not a hack--that would still have the parent fully owning the state and keep the child totally dumb.

Comment: @MikeJ thanks for taking the time to comment. Using ViewChild/Children as you describe is exactly what I was thinking. Probably it's the only solution available. The thing that bothers me is that I would, more or less, write an alternative change detection strategy, mapping by hand the changing (or not changing values) every time they change. Possibly clean from an architectural standpoint, but quite ugly in terms of code duplication/robustness/ease of maintenance. It would "play differently" from every other component in the application.